# About Fréchet and Gateaux derivatives.

Tags: linear-transformations, calculus-of-variations

just studying some variational calculus, but i got stuck in a question about linear normal spaces. I know that it may seem obvious that for a R $\in$ $L(X,Y)$ (which is the normal vector space for all linear and continous transformations between X,Y) we have that $R''=0$, but I just don't get it. How can I arrive to that result? Thanks for reading.

P.S R'', refers to the second Fréchet derivative.

Comment: $R'$ is constant, so $R'' = 0$. This is true even for arbitrary spaces $X,Y$, interpreted correctly - $R'(x)$ takes the constant value $R'(x) = R\in L(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to demonstrate from first principles.  If we take the definition of the Gâteaux derivative and apply it to a linear operator $R\in {\cal L}(X,Y)$ at some point $x\in X$ we have
$$R'(x)(h) =: \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{R(x+th)-R(x)}{t} $$
for all $h\in X$.
Since $R$ is linear we see that $R(x+th) = R(x)+tR(h)$ and so substituting that in above, we get
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
R'(x)(h) &=& \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{R(x)+tR(h)-R(x)}{t} \\
{}& = & \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}R(h) \\
{}& = & R(h)
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Thus $R'(x)$ is constant (as mentioned in the comments).  Taking the derivative of a constant is zero, so $R''(x) = 0 \ \forall x \in X$.

This leaves the case of the Fréchet derivative for you to do yourself, but it's very similar.